# rest_in_place select within a .each for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the `rest_in_place` gem within Rails 3 to perform in-place edits within a table returning the results from a model.

For editing text inputs I have had no issues.  For one of my `<td>` fields I would like the field, when clicked on for editing, to have a select drop down box populated from a User model that has users within the system.

I attempted to use the following code within my model but it seems `rest_in_place` is expecting this element to be within a form.

HTML:

```
<td style="font-size: 10px;"><span class="rest-in-place" data-select="AbaseUser" data-formtype="select" data-object="marketer_import" data-attribute="new_user" data-url="<%= "/marketer_imports/#{marketer_import.id}" %>">
  <%= marketer_import.new_username unless marketer_import.new_username.nil? %>
</span></td>
```

Javascript:

```
RestInPlaceEditor.prototype.bindForm = function() {
  this.activateForm = RestInPlaceEditor.forms[this.formType].activateForm;
  return this.getValue = RestInPlaceEditor.forms[this.formType].getValue;
};
```

I get the following error within the Chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'activateForm' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see [here](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place), rest_in_place doesn't support 'select' form type by default (only input & textarea). Consider using [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) instead. 
[Ryan Bates](https://twitter.com/rbates) offers a nice tutorial [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing).